# Confidence about the likely size of a fair dice from only a single roll

Tags: probability, bayesian

Conundrum: If I roll a die of unknown sides, can I have any degree of confidence about the size of the die based only on that single outcome (aside from the tautology that it must have at least the size of the roll)?

Let's say I roll a 6. To what degree (if at all) am I justified in saying that the die is more likely to be 6-sided than 12-sided?

On one hand, rolling a 6 on a 12-sided die isn't anything remarkable; any single roll is unremarkable in isolation. On the other hand, rolling 6 on a 12-sided die is less likely than rolling 6 on a 6-sided die. Which of these cases are "more important" to this question?

For example: can we invoke Bayes factor?

H1 = 6-sided die
H2 = 12-sided die
O = we rolled a 6
K = P(O | H1) / P(O | H2)
P(O | H1) = 1/6 and P(O | H2) = 1/12
K = 12/6 = 2

Which shows non-trivial confidence that the die is 6-sided rather than 12-sided. Am I in the right for thinking like this?

Comment: Assuming that your first roll is a 6, if you know that the die has either exactly 6 sides or exactly 12 sides, then the probability that it is 6 sided is $$\frac{(1/2) \times (1/6)}{[(1/2) \times (1/6)] + [(1/2) \times (1/12)]} = \frac{2}{3},$$ based on [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).  One idea is to use this approach and assume that (for example) the number of sides on the die is some random number between $~1~$ and $~100.$  Then, if you roll a $~6,~$ you have to consider $~95~$ possibilities, instead of only $~2~$ possibilities.

Comment: This interesting question is a stripped down version of the German tank problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem